# Problems with fixed footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have the following site: http://latest-mtv.net/ev , on this page and other pages everything works perfect... but on this page http://latest-mtv.net/ev/index.php?p=2 I need the footer to go down...to the end..where the content finishes(under the content). I haven't found any solutions to work on both scenarios, mabe you guys can help me please.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "position: fixed" for your footer.

Comment: If I do that the footer disappears

Comment: Because of others divs z-index? Change footer to "position: relative" instead.

Comment: Almost works now http://latest-mtv.net/ev/index.php?p=2 but the footer isn't snapped to the bottom...i guess it's a float problem..or JS...mabe you can see it...faster than me..thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, add to footer "margin-top: 51px;"